# Sqlite and Python, wildcard after equals

Tags: python, sqlite

I have the following code

```
def function(foo):
    #Function that counts records in db with SB = 0 and SO = foo
    #SO takes the values {0,1}

    SQL = """ SELECT Count(*) FROM EvaluatedPlays
              WHERE
              SB = 0
              AND SO = ?
          """

    data = SQLfunctions.fetchSQL(SQL, foo)
    #This queries the db with the above SQL and foo as a binding

    return data
```

My question is, can I use a value for `foo` (some sort of wildcard) that will count all records such that just `SB = 0` i.e. the value of `SO` doesn't matter? If not I will have to right a whole new query to do this which I'd rather not do due to readability and redundancy issues.

Comment: While you could, and it might be less redundant, I actually think having a separate function would make things more readable. Otherwise your one function does 2 different things.

Comment: @HankDitton: Well, you could make the same argument for, e.g., any Python function that has a parameter with a default value (or a `*args` parameter, etc.). There's clearly a tradeoff here, not an open-shut answer.

Comment: @abarnert Yes, I'm not claiming one way is definitively better than the other. Just that there is nothing wrong with writing two functions.

Comment: @HankDitton: Agreed. Or, maybe, even if there is something "wrong" with it, in some cases there's a lot more wrong with all of the other alternatives, so it's still the right/obvious/pythonic thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no value that matches all values.

You *could* merge the two queries into one more complicated query—e.g., a `LIKE` instead of `=` that's either a non-wildcard string or a pure-wildcard string, or something like `(? IS NULL OR SO = ?)` that takes the parameter twice. But these are likely to be less readable, rather than more, and may cause a performance hit as well.

In situations like this, it may be reasonable to format the SQL statements dynamically—you're not formatting in any *user* data, or generating an open-ended set of different statements, just two specific ones. So:

```
    SQL = """ SELECT Count(*) FROM EvaluatedPlays
          WHERE
          SB = 0"""
    if foo is not None:
        SQL += "AND SO = ?"
    cursor.execute(SQL, [foo] if foo is not None else [])
```

You could make the SQL a bit more complicated, so it uses `?` in a way where it has no effect instead of not using it at all, allowing you to pass the parameter unconditionally. But that can be very confusing to a reader.

And you can find ways to wrap this up more generically, but you'll have to be careful that you're not opening the doors to SQL injection, a combinatorial explosion of statements (which may ruin the database's statement cache), etc.

And of course you can always push the logic of making the switch based on the parameter value into a stored procedure (with SQLite this can even just be a function in your script), but that can be a pretty over-complicated solution for such a simple use case.

So, you'll often find that it looks cleaner and more readable to just have two different statements.